# Set and unset windows proxy with script

Tags: windows, proxy

I need to set the Windows proxy very often and manually doing the procedure is a terrible pain. Is there any way to create a script? I need to set the following things:

- automatic configuration script address
- enable and disable proxy
- ip and port of the proxy
- flag to avoid local connections to go through the proxy
- set exceptions

Comment: Use this [PowerShell script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-function-Get-cba2abf5), direct from Microsoft Technet. By the way, this site is called Unix & Linux. Windows is neither Unix nor Linux

Comment: Thanks for the lin @AlexP. Which site would be a better fit?

Comment: Maybe [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Today is not my best day. Is there any way to move the question there?